# Is $B=\{f \in C_b(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)| f(x) > 0 \rbrace $ open and what is its interior?

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let $B=\{f \in C_b(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)| f(x) > 0$ for all $ x \in \Bbb R \}$ where $C_b$ are functions that are both continuous and bounded. Is $B$ open and what is the interior of $B$?

**My attempt:**
$B$ is not open. Take $f(x)=1/n$, $g(x)=-1/n$ constant functions where $n \in \Bbb N$ then considering $\Bbb R$ as a metric space with the standard metric and $d(f,g)= sup \{d(f(x),g(x))| x \in A \}$ we have for any $\epsilon >0$ that 
$|d(f,g)| = |2/n|$ which can be made arbitrarily small so that any epsilon ball around $f$ will contain a function that is not always positive, hence $B$ cannot be open.

Now as for the interior I have no idea where to start on this and am in need of a hint. Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should state what topology you consider on $C_b(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier is that better? I'm new to some of these concepts. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: And your reasoning in the attempt is false. You have to pick a function, and show then that for a sufficiently small epsilon, you can find another functions close by epsilon that are in the set B. What you do is you pick two functions and then state that they are too far away, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ user401855 . I disagree. What I am saying is that for that particular function, any epsilon ball will contain a function not in $B$, so the entire set can't be open.

Comment: Suppose $f$ takes arbitrarily small positive values. Can it be in the interior?

Comment: @user401855 It makes no sense to write $B=f^{-1}(\ldots)$, $f$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yes, that's one possible topology. But I believe it would be better to include it in the question, rather than in the attempt.

Comment: To make a concrete example illustrating why the argument structure is invalid: $(0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, yet there are points $\frac{1}{n} \in (0, 1)$ and $-\frac{1}{n} \notin (0, 1)$ which are arbitrarily close.

Comment: @DanielSchepler right good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to look at this: let $f\in B$ be such that $\inf(f)=0$. That means, that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $x_\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<f(x_\epsilon)<\epsilon$. If we let $f_\epsilon(x)=f(x)-\epsilon$, then $f_\epsilon(x_\epsilon)<0$, and so $f_\epsilon$ is not in $B$. It is clearly in $C_b(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. Since $d(f,f_\epsilon)=\epsilon$, we see there are points arbitrarily close to $f$ that are not in $B$.  Thus no neighborhood of $f$ is contained in $B$, and so $f\notin\operatorname{int}(B)$.

On the other hand, if $\inf(f)=\delta>0$, then if $d(f,g)<\delta/2$, we have 
\begin{align}
g(x) &= f(x) - \left(f(x) - g(x)\right) \\
&\ge f(x) - |f(x) - g(x)|\\
&\ge \delta - \delta/2\\
&> 0
\end{align}

so $B_{\delta/2}(f)\subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2).$ Then $f\in B.$ For $n=1,2,\dots,$ define functions $g_n$ in $C_b\setminus B$ as follows: $g_n(x) = f(x), x\le n,$ $g_n(x)$ is the linear function on $[n,n+1]$ whose graph connects $(n,f(n))$ and $(n+1,0),$ and $g_n(x) = 0, x\ge n+1.$ Note that

$$\|g_n-f\|_{C_b} \le f(n)\,\, \text {for all } n.$$

Thus $(g_n)$ is a sequence in $C_b\setminus B$ that converges to $f$ in $C_b.$ This proves that no $B(f,r ),r>0,$ is contained in $B.$ Thus $B$ is not open in $C_b.$

As for the interior of $B:$ Consider $\{f\in B: \inf_{\mathbb R} f>0\}.$

Comment: Can I generalize that any function that doesn't have inf f>0 that by defining $g(x)$ the same way you did will yield the same sequence and result?

Comment: Similar but not exactly the same. A little more complicated because we don't necessarly have a function that $\to 0$ at $\pm \infty.$ For example, what would you do with $1/(1+x^2)+\sin^2x?$

Comment: This seems overly complicated. For any $\epsilon>0$, just note that $f-\epsilon$ is not in $B$. Thus no open ball around $f$ is contained in $B$.

Comment: @SteveD You're right, that's much easier than what I was thinking.

Comment: @SteveD  Why not write up your simpler proof as an answer? I would think it would then be the accepted answer, fine with me.